# Datepicker Laravel Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, datepicker

I am researching in the internet for datepicker and found this code,

```
      {{ Form::label('dateA','Date Aquired')}}
      {{ Form::text('startingDate', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-sm','placeholder' => 'Starting Date','data-provide' => 'datepicker')) }}
```

a lot of comments says that this code is working, but mine is not, it just outputs a texbox. Do I need to include some script or css when using datepicker? thanks.

Comment: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1):

You need to include scripts and stylesheets for bootstrap, jquery, moment.js and the specific date picker you are trying to use.

There are installation instructions here:

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/wiki/Installation

Specifically this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap/js/transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap/js/collapse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

If you are using blade templates you can do your urls like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
```

...where the folder `css` is in your `public` folder.

With that many dependencies it is probably worth it to learn [bower](http://bower.io/) and use the bower instructions from the above link.